# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject array

Tags: c#

I have JSON string like this :

```
"Info":[
{"Type":{"Value":"pointA"},"X":0.2,"Y":0.22},
{"Type":{"Value":"pointB"},"X":0.3"Y":0.33}
]
```

I would like to convert to my class like below by using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

```
public class TestPoins
    {
        PointF pointA { get; set; }
        PointF pointB { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried:

```
TestPoins test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< TestPoins >(strJson);
```

The error is: `Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TestPoints'`

Comment: Is that valid `json`?

Comment: Is there really no comma in `"X":0.3"Y":0.33` ?

Comment: Where is your PointF class?

Comment: I assumed it was `System.Drawing.PointF`

Comment: Once you fix the errors in the `json`, visit [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) then post your `json` into the editor, it will model the classes you need.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, recent versions have an option named "Paste JSON as classes" kinda useful

Comment: There is no way an automated deserialization would generate the `Testpoins` class with the properties `pointA` and `pointB` from that JSON. You will need to code it after the deserialization has been done.

Comment: @Codexer I disagree on the edit rollback you did in this question. It fixed the JSON still making the question valid.

Comment: @Cleptus who's to say the OP isn't constructing this json and or receiving the json this way (another issue); there's more than a few errors in that json. Also the error message isn't correct with the class name either, not the issue at hand, but providing us with replicable code to reproduce helps us help them. The OP needs to clarify this, I've mentioned it ~37 minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

Your Class Properties Does not map because they are incorrect.
You should Generate Your Class Like This :

```
public partial class Temperatures
{
    [JsonProperty("Info")]
    public Info[] Info { get; set; }
}

public partial class Info
{
    [JsonProperty("Type")]
    public TypeClass Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("X")]
    public double X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Y")]
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public partial class TypeClass
{
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: no i just convert json to c# class model and compared it with that.

Comment: This solution deserializes the json but does not result in a `TestPoins` class

Comment: This answer, as-is, is partial. It only addresses how to deserialize, but not how to get into the structure OP wants.

Comment: thak you works :var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Info>>(str);

Comment: Dear Friend my class name is defferent but the functionality is correct.

Comment: If is it correct please set it as correct answer for others.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably create a JsonConverter to make this happen, but you can also brute force it. Here I am using JObject and JArray to get the data out of the json and manually building a TestPoins class instance. I have fixed the json so it is valid and also made your TestPoins properties public.

If you have LINQPad you can try [this script](http://share.linqpad.net/ixbcqx.linq)

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{
        ""Info"": [{
                ""Type"": {
                    ""Value"": ""pointA""
                },
                ""X"": 0.2,
                ""Y"": 0.22
            },
            {
                ""Type"": {
                    ""Value"": ""pointB""
                },
                ""X"": 0.3,
                ""Y"": 0.33
            }
        ]
    }";

    JObject info = JObject.Parse(json);

    JArray points = info["Info"] as JArray;

    TestPoins test = new TestPoins();

    foreach (JObject element in points)
    {
        ConvertToPoint(test, element);
    }

    //test is your object
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class TestPoins
{
    public PointF pointA { get; set; }
    public PointF pointB { get; set; }
}

void ConvertToPoint(TestPoins points, JObject obj)
{
    var x = obj["X"].Value<float>();
    var y = obj["Y"].Value<float>();
    PointF pt = new PointF(x, y);

    if (obj["Type"]["Value"].Value<string>() == "pointA")
    {
        points.pointA = pt;
    }
    else
    {
        points.pointB = pt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can automatically transform that JSON because the pointA data and pointB data are in an array.

If you paste it into Visual Studio (special paste -> paste JSON as classes) you will get a similar classes to the following ones.

```
public class JSONRoot
{
    public JSONInfo[] Info { get; set; }
}

public class JSONInfo
{
    public JSONType Type { get; set; }
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
}

public class JSONType
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now you only have to loop the `JSONInfo[]` array and retrieve the data you want.

```
JSONRoot jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONInfo>(strJson);
TestPoins pointsInfo = new TestPoins();
foreach(JSONInfo item in jsonData.Info)
{
    if(item.Value == "pointA")
    {
        pointsInfo.pointA = new Pointf(item.X, item.Y);
    }
}
```